# insert Qrcode in to existing Pdf file every page

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to insert a QR code into every page of a PDF file. Initially, the 'output.pdf' file has three pages, but when I run the code below, the QR code is inserted successfully into the PDF file. However, many pages are missing, and the resulting 'output.pdf' file becomes a single page. How can I fix this issue? Below is the code I am using

````
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def generate_qr(data):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
    return img

# Generate QR code
qr_img = generate_qr('https://www.example.com')
qr_image_path = "qr_temp.png"
qr_img.save(qr_image_path)

# Create the watermark from an image
c = canvas.Canvas('watermark.pdf')
c.drawImage(qr_image_path, 15, 720, width=120, height=120)  # add your desired position here
c.save()

# Get the watermark file you just created
watermark = PdfReader('watermark.pdf')

# Get our files ready
output = PdfWriter()
input_pdf = PdfReader('input.pdf')

# Go through all the input file pages to add a watermark to them
for page_number in range(len(input_pdf.pages)):
    print(f"Watermarking page {page_number} of {len(input_pdf.pages)}")
    page = input_pdf.pages[page_number]
    watermark_page = watermark.pages[0]
    watermark_page.mediabox = page.mediabox  # to make the size of watermark page same as original page
    page.merge_page(watermark_page)
    output.add_page(page)

# Finally, write the output to a file
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
    output.write(outputStream)

# Clean up temporary files
import os
os.remove(qr_image_path)
os.remove('watermark.pdf') ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do it with PyMuPDF:

```py
import qrcode
import io
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

fitz.TOOLS.set_aa_level(0)  # set anti-aiasing level to 0

def make_qrcode():
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data("Some data")
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    fp = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(fp, "PNG")
    return fp


rect = fitz.Rect(15, 15, 135, 135)  # top left square, 120 points edge len
stream = make_qrcode()  # QR code as PNG image in memory

doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")

for page in doc:
    page.insert_image(rect, stream=stream)

doc.save("output.pdf", deflate=True, garbage=3)
```

Comment: img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")   I am not shre because of this or not when send to the print shop they say this is not hundred percent black Not hundred percent K (it come from mik CMY) I try  qr.make_image(back_color=(255, 255, 255), fill_color=(0, 0, 0)) it also not 100%k

Comment: What you can try: Set a global variable in PyMuPDF `fitz.TOOLS.set_aa_level(0)`which is the anti-aliasing level. This forces a maximum of "pixelization". Should give you a true b/w picture. This instruction should be executed right after importing fitz.