# Inserting QR code into the existing pdf file using python

Tags: python, pdf, qr-code

using this link [insert Qrcode in to existing Pdf file every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436485/insert-qrcode-in-to-existing-pdf-file-every-page/76667987#76667987), I can generate and insert the QR code into my pdf, but while I scan the QR code using my mobile, QR is not scanned when the pdf is in 100% zoom level, I need to increase the zoom size to 200% to get QR scanned. I want the QR to be placed in the right top corner of the pdf and to be scanned in 100% zoom level itself. Can anyone help me on this please?

Generated QR code using python, inserted QR code into pdf file.

Comment: Hi Rprakash! Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: it sounds like you need to make the QR code double the size

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3929826)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have much data in your qrcode, so you have to increase the box size and also it's border like this:

```py
import qrcode
import io
import fitz

def make_qrcode():
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=20,
        border=6,
    )
    qr.add_data("Some data")
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    fp = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(fp, "PNG")
    return fp
```

Comment: I tried the above approach, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This modified code, sets the anti-aliasing level to 0 for a true black&white QR code image and puts it at the page's top right corner with a size of 204 x 240. We also leave a page margin of 20 points.

```py
import qrcode
import io
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

fitz.TOOLS.set_aa_level(0)  # set anti-aiasing level to 0
margin = 20  # ensure QR rect keeps this distance from page border

def make_qrcode():
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data("Some data")
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    fp = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(fp, "PNG")
    return fp

stream = make_qrcode()  # QR code as PNG image in memory

doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")

for page in doc:
    w = page.rect.width  # width of this page
    left = w - 240 - margin
    rect = fitz.Rect(left, margin, left + 240, margin + 240)  # top right square
    page.insert_image(rect, stream=stream)

doc.save("output.pdf", deflate=True, garbage=3)
```

Comment: thanks. it works for me. setting margin = 20 will work for all types of pdf? also can we define the size of QR code that we are generating? for example 3' x 3' or 4' x 4' like this?

Comment: The margin number will be good for all pages that aren't smaller than that value (plus the QR square side length) in width or height. As per the QR code generator: I have no experience with that thing at all. But from the answer from @OmidRoshani I would assume that you can play with the `box_size` and `border` parameters.